# I need to map a database name in a inner join based on a column value from another database nabe,need to use a concat function in the inner join

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My query is below.I need to join a database table co to many other database table based on a column id match.

```
select con.id,u.user_id,co.id
from catalogue.orders co 
inner join catalogue.reference r on r.id=co.item_reference_id
inner join concat('context_',left(co.subscriber_reference,locate("W",co.subscriber_reference)-1)).orders con on con.id=co.id
inner join concat('context_',left(co.subscriber_reference,locate("W",co.subscriber_reference)-1)).user_id u on con.user_id=co.user_id
where co.subscriber_reference='2WW10005'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Luk, I need certain columns from both database and they are joined based on the order id split. i.e. if subscriber_reference =2WW10005, the 2 in front should look for database - context_2 and the 10005 is a column in context_2.orders.id=10005. I have one main database which is catalogue and captures the orders. And then every order is related to a context which the details are stored in different databases. I need a general query to query different databases based on the split of that Id.